# How do I write a regex to match the following number formats?

Tags: c++, regex

I am fairly new to writing regexes.

I need to match the following patterns (all numbers) with a single regex.
Each of the following is a valid pattern I want to match.
Finding any of them should satisfy the regex

Each # symbol is one digit [0-9]

```
##################      
#### #### #### #### ##  
######## ##########     
##########
```

18 digits, no delimiters 
18 digits delimited 
10 digits

I tried this to match the 10 digits and it does not match.

```
(?: \d{10} )
```

Comment: Language is a concern since regex is different from one another. JavaScript, C++, ,...?

Comment: @zer00ne - thanks - C++ - I updated the tags

Comment: Did you want the space before and after the 10 digit number?

Comment: So each `#` represents any single digit? Are those new lines or is it one line wrapped around?

Comment: Here's an example that will capture all 4 of your patterns (only 1 at a time): /(?=(\d{18})) | (?=(\d{10})) | (?=((?>\d{4}[-.]){4}\d{2})) | (?=(\d{5}[-.]\d{5}))/  I'll post an answer and explain the regex a bit

Comment: It's pretty simple really `^####(?:[ ]####[ ]####[ ]####[ ]##|####(?:[ ]##########|##(?:########)?))$` where each # is a digit.

Comment: Then there is this `^\d{4}(?: (?:\d{4} ){3}\d{2}|\d{4}(?: \d{10}|\d{2}(?:\d{8})?))$` https://regex101.com/r/Dnvdok/1

Answer (score 1):

(Note I'm not sure if this will work in C++, but it's working regex in a normal online regex-checker)
(EDIT: your question doesn't specify what your delimiter is.  I'm using '.' or '-', but they can be replaced by anything, such as '\s')

`(?=(\d{18}))|(?=(\d{10}))|(?=((?>\d{4}[-.]){4}\d{2}))|(?=(\d{5}[-.]\d{5}))`

Let me break this down:

- Each `|` between `(?=...)` groups is a logical OR.  The regex will return the first group that successfully matches.
- `(?=...)` means "positive look ahead"
- `(?=(\d{18}))` Return a group of 18 consecutive digits [0-9]
- `(?=(\d{10}))` Return a group of 10 consecutive digits [0-9]
- `(?=((?>\d{4}[-.]){4}\d{2}))` Return a group that follows a pattern of (4 consecutive digits followed by either a '.' or '-') repeated 4 times (the pattern, not the exact values), followed by 2 digits.  The `(?>...)` bit just means "don't capture this group"
- `(?=(\d{5}[-.]\d{5}))` Return a group of 5 consecutive digits followed by a '.' or '-' followed by 5 more digits

This is by no means the only way to write this, and somebody else may have a more elegant solution.  But this works!

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
(\d *){17}\d|\d{10}
```

The first option matches any 17 digits followed by 0 or more spaces, followed by an 18th digit. The second option only matches 10 consecutive digits.

If you want a max of one space between digits, you can do this instead:

```
(\d ?){17}\d|\d{10}
```

Note that the matches will still have the spaces in them, so you'll want to remove the spaces from them after.

If there can be other delimiters like `-` you can use a character list like:

```
(\d[- ]?){17}\d|\d{10}
```